# Load data from database: Template7 and Framework7

Tags: javascript, cordova, template-engine, html-framework-7

I am using Template7 and Framework7 to build an iOS app using PhoneGap. I am going through the [tutorial](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/template7-pages.html#.VngWBuN97fY)

my-app.js file

```
// Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7({
    init: false
});

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Because we use fixed-through navbar we can enable dynamic navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true
});

myApp.onPageInit('index', function (page) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {}
});

myApp.init();

// Callbacks to run specific code for specific pages, for example for About page:
myApp.onPageInit('about', function (page) {
    console.log('Baga');
    // run createContentPage func after link was clicked
    $$('.create-page').on('click', function () {
        createContentPage();
    });
});

// Generate dynamic page
var dynamicPageIndex = 0;
function createContentPage() {
    mainView.router.loadContent(

        '<!-- Top Navbar-->' +
        '<div class="navbar">' +
        '  <div class="navbar-inner">' +
        '    <div class="left"><a href="#" class="back link"><i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>' +
        '    <div class="center sliding">Dynamic Page ' + (++dynamicPageIndex) + '</div>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="pages">' +
        '  <!-- Page, data-page contains page name-->' +
        '  <div data-page="dynamic-pages" class="page">' +
        '    <!-- Scrollable page content-->' +
        '    <div class="page-content">' +
        '      <div class="content-block">' +
        '        <div class="content-block-inner">' +
        '          <p>Here is a dynamic page created on ' + new Date() + ' !</p>' +
        '          <p>Go <a href="#" class="back">back</a> or go to <a href="services.html">Services</a>.</p>' +
        '        </div>' +
        '      </div>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
    return;
}
```

How do I use template7data in

```
myApp.onPageInit('index', function (page) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {}
});
```

and load data in it from database or from some AJAX query. I want to use that data to display content on index.html file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You need to have a template. For example:

   ```
   <script id="template" type="text/template7">
       <p>Hello, my name is {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</p>
   </script>
   ```
2. Compile the template with Template7:

   ```
   var template = $$('#template').html();
   var compiledTemplate = Template7.compile(template);
   ```
3. Get your JSON data from the server:

   ```
   $$.getJSON('link/to/your/json', {}, function (data) {          
       var context = data;
   }
   ```
4. Now render the compiled template by passing required context

   ```
   var html = compiledTemplate(context);
   ```

Now, the `html` variable will contain the html you need. For example:

```
    <p>Hello, my name is John Doe</p>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me I get this error: Template7: Template must be a string

Answer (score -2):

Template7 is a mobile-first JavaScript template engine with Handlebars-like syntax. It is used as default template engine in Framework7

It is ultra lightweight (around 1KB minified and gzipped) and blazing fast (up to 2-3 times faster than Handlebars in mobile Safari).

https://jsfiddle.net/aslamshaikh14/jexs43va/

https://youtu.be/rVM-vDQelpE

`Template7`